# Fetching data from the other sites and displaying into our page.?

Tags: java, jsp

Is ther any way to get data from other sites and display in our jsp pages dynamically.

http://www.dictionary30.com/meaning/Misty  see this url
in that one block is like
Wikipedia Meaning and Definition on 'Misty'
 In that block they are fetching the data from Wikipedia and displaying into dictionaly30.
Question:
How they are fetching wiki data to their site.?
I need to display data like that in my jsp page by fetching from other site.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and read other site's data.

or better you use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) it will also parse specific data for you from some other site.

for your case

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://www.dictionary30.com/meaning/Misty"), 10000);
Element div = document.select("div[id=contentbox]").first();

System.out.println(div.html());
```

Comment: Thanks allot...its really usefull, and can i knom how twits are displaying in the section "Sample Sentence from Social Media on 'Misty' " in the site http://www.dictionary30.com/meaning/Misty

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch data from other site on your server side using `URLConnection` and provide this data to jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure you get permission first from the site owners before doing anything like that.
Most people don't take kindly to their data being leeched by others, especially as it costs them money and doesn't generate any (advertising) income.

It's also very risky in that your own site/application will quickly fail as soon as the site you're leeching from gets changed to a different layout.